# STM32F746 I2S clock fails

Tags: stm32, audio, i2s, hal

I have discovery board STM32f746NG
In first try I've set this:
Activate I2S2 with piout: PB4->WS - PI3->SD - PI1->CK.
[image]

Instantly after activating I2S periferal with command `__HAL_I2S_ENABLE(&hi2s2);` the clocks must begins, but I sense 0v at CK and SD and +3.3 on WS.

Also in case of transmission, serial debugger shows timeout (w8s for TXE to set, but it never set after first clearing it) error after executing `HAL_I2S_Transmit()` function and this make I2S busy forever, it seems it try to send but, can't send and does not generate clock.

Also I've not used BCLK original pin I've remapped it.
full code is here:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

I2S_HandleTypeDef hi2s2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2S2_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2S2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  __HAL_I2S_ENABLE(&hi2s2);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  uint16_t buf=12;
  HAL_I2S_Transmit(&hi2s2, &buf, 1, 100000  );
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 300;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2S2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2S2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S2_Init 1 */
  hi2s2.Instance = SPI2;
  hi2s2.Init.Mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER_TX;
  hi2s2.Init.Standard = I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS;
  hi2s2.Init.DataFormat = I2S_DATAFORMAT_16B;
  hi2s2.Init.MCLKOutput = I2S_MCLKOUTPUT_ENABLE;
  hi2s2.Init.AudioFreq = I2S_AUDIOFREQ_8K;
  hi2s2.Init.CPOL = I2S_CPOL_LOW;
  hi2s2.Init.ClockSource = I2S_CLOCK_PLL;
  if (HAL_I2S_Init(&hi2s2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOI_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Exactly the same code has run on STM32h743vit and it has generated the requred clock.
I think maybe the hardware have malfunction due to damage?!

Comment: Which is normal? Why would there be anything on the clock line if there is no transmission happening? Unfortunately, can't help much further. I haven't worked with I2S yet. Maybe someone else will have something to add to this. I could only suggest basic checks, which we did.

Comment: @Ilya In HAL library they've told periphal does work to prevent desynchronization. I think it mean's in I2S we need constant clock in CLK and WS both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same code has run on STM32h743vit and it has generated the requred clock. I think maybe the hardware have malfunction due to damage?!